# grails different config files for multiple server

Tags: tomcat, grails

currently I'm trying to setup config files for each ip my application is running.

Here is a part of my `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "file:web-app/WEB-INF/conf/${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}.groovy",
    "file:web-app/WEB-INF/conf/dataSource/${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}.properties"
]
```

that works locally but on tomcat not because there is no folder `web-app`, so I added:

```
"file:WEB-INF/conf/${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}.groovy",
"file:WEB-INF/conf/dataSource/${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}.properties"
```

But that still doesn't work.

How can I get the tomcat to load the config files correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When starting tomcat in your catalina opts :

Configuration location for external config - called in Config.groovy

```
* JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DCONFIGLOC=conf/"
* now it will look for {tomcatbase}/conf/{appname}/{appname}Config.groovy
```

Then in your [Config.groovy](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/51ab6484312767ac933676da349dcb48f1cf3911/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L24):

```
if (System.getProperty('CONFIGLOC')) {
    externalConfigPath='file:'+System.getProperty('CONFIGLOC')+File.separator+appName+File.separator
}
```